# simplicial approximation of an open subset

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I am interested in the following problem :

Let $K$ be an abstract simplicial complex, let $\vert K \vert$ be its geometrical realization, let $U\subset \vert K \vert$ be an open subspace (not a subcomplex). Is it possible to find some subdivision $K^*$ of $K$ and a subcomplex $L\subset K^*$ such that $U$ is a deformation retract of the geometric realization $\vert L \vert$?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Not in general, because in particular $U$ would be homotopy equivalent to a finite cell complex. Take for example $K$ to be a 1-simplex and $U$ to be the complement of a Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to see if my open set has some additional property

Comment: In case it's useful: there is a triangulation $T$ of $U$ such that every simplex of $T$ is contained linearly in a simplex of $K$.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams: I'm not seeing why $U$ would have to be homotopy equivalent to a finite complex, unless perhaps we assume that $K$ is finite. At any rate, replacing "finite" with "locally finite" probably gives the same issue.

Comment: I was assuming that K is finite.